# What is the actual complex formed in Fehling's solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

What is the actual complex formed in Fehling's solution when Fehling’s solution A and Fehling’s solution B are mixed in equal amount?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehling%27s_solution) suggests: $\ce{[Cu(C4H4O6)2]^2-}$

But the [book](https://ncert.nic.in/pdf/publication/sciencelaboratorymanuals/classXII/chemistry/lelm108.pdf) I follow suggests: $\ce{[Cu2(C4H4O6)2]}$ .
It states the structure of the complex as:
[image: Copper tartarate complex]

Another source suggests the structure as:

[image]

So, the complex a/c to the above [source](https://www.marefa.org/images/thumb/6/65/Fehling_orz.svg/800px-Fehling_orz.svg.png) is $\ce{[Cu(C4H4O6)2]^4-}$

So, altogether my questions are:

1. What is the actual structure of *the* complex?
2. How many copper ions are actually coordinated?
3. To neutralize the charge, do Cu(II) ions act as counter ions(e.g.: considering of Wikipedia : $\ce{Cu[Cu(C_4H_4O_6)2]}$ )?

Comment: H in bound OH frequently goes away as H+, e.g. in citrate complexes. // ACS has some paywalled article https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01501a013

Comment: You didn't read Wikipedia carefully "The tartrate serves as a ligand. However, the coordination chemistry is complex and various species with different metal to ligand ratio have been determined."

Comment: I had read that @Mithoron and there are several citations too. But I was in a search for a "commonly adopted structure" or such like which has major proportion in the solution(due to their different stabilities). Their stabilities comparisons(although, yes they are unstable but we can state their 'relative' stabilities). Moreover besides *that* statement , why Wikipedia stressed over $\ce{[Cu(C4H4O6)2]^2-}$ ? Altogether, I was in a search for a more rigorous answer. At least it could bring some good answers(and some knowledge and clarity to me).

Comment: As far as *formula* is concerned [Cu(C4H4O6)2]2− is most reasonable one, but it obviously depends on pH (forget this monster with two Cu ions).

Comment: Tetraanion is unlikely and if it could be made, reagent wouldn't decompose to hydroxide, I think.